# Performing an Group By Function in SQL in Marketing Cloud Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, sql, activities

I'm trying to perform a Group By function on my Click data view Data Extension, which was built from the _Click data view. (Not sure if it's necessary to have the extra layer.) I am looking to aggregate my data so I can build a report that combines all sends (regular/user-initiated + journey builder) and will have all send JobID's (including the ones from Journey Builder)

Here's the SQL script that I tried:

```
SELECT AccountID, OYBAccountID, JobID, ListID, EventDate, TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID, 
TriggeredSendCustomerKey
From "Click data view"
WHERE EventDate between '2020-01-01' and '2020-02-01'
GROUP BY "JobID"
```

But I am getting the following error:

> An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Column
>   'C6169540.Click data view.AccountID' is invalid in the select list
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would defer to reading up on the group by function at w3 schools, https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a SQL issue and not Marketing Cloud specific. Any field that is in your select list BUT is not in your group by, will need to be wrapped in a function such as min(), max(), average(), etc. Since they are not grouped fields, they will have multiple values and need summarized via an aggregate function.